# Open Contact information in Contact List using Phone Number of Contact Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am making a little app that has to do with phone numbers.

My question is I have a phone number that is in my Contact List in my phone.
Example: 0877777777

I would like to open that Contacts information using that phone number.

Just to clarify the when I say contact list I mean the Contacts saved on my Phone.

If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`PhoneLookup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) api is meant just for this.

```
String number = "0877777777";
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
String[] projection = new String[]{ PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

Cursor cur = getContentresolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

if (cur != null) {
   while (cur.moveToNext()) {
      Long id = cur.getLong(0);
      String name = cur.getString(1);
      Log.d("My Contacts", "found: " + id + " - " + name);
   }
   cur.close();
}
```

**UPDATE**

To open the contact's profile in the stock contacts app, you need to first get the contact's `CONTACT_ID`, and then use it in an `Intent` to the external app:

```
String number = "0877777777";
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
String[] projection = new String[]{ PhoneLookup._ID };

Cursor cur = getContentresolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

// if other contacts have that phone as well, we simply take the first contact found.
if (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    Long id = cur.getLong(0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
    intent.setData(contactUri);
    context.startActivity(intent);

    cur.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answere. My question is how do I put this into an intent to show the contact in the Contacts?

Comment: Hi thanks for your update. I am getting an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column contact_id. Do you know where this might come from?

Comment: i've answered this on your new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45043662/819355 (no need to open multiple Qs for the same problem BTW)