# Error in looking up a contact Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am getting an error when I want to access the a specific contact.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column contact_id

Here is the sample code:

```
String number = "0877777777";
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
                String[] projection = new String[]{ ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID };

                Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

                // if other contacts have that phone as well, we simply take the first contact found.
                if (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
                    Long id = cur.getLong(0);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
                    intent.setData(contactUri);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    cur.close();
                }
```

The error is in the projection but I am not sure how to fix it.
The number is saved on the phone under test.
Any advice on solving the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup` contains only 3 columns. No Contact_id there. TO use this column, you should Join with Contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID` to `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID`.

The `_ID` in `PhoneLookup` simply mean the `CONTACT_ID`

See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTACT_ID`

Comment: That will give me a android.net.Uri . How would I implement that in the above code?